# Search for build number on TeamCity via REST API

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-rest-api

We give our builds unique build numbers, that include a timestamp and a git commit. Given one of these build numbers (and *no* other information), I want to find the build configuration that built it.

If I type the build number into the "Search" box in the upper right corner, it works fine, listing the build and noting:

```
1 build found (matches in build number — 1) in 662ms
```

How do I access the same information via the REST API? I have checked the [API docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API), but can't see a call equivalent to the generic "Search" exposed in the UI. Alternatively, I'd like to directly fetch the Build details and/or Build Configuration (http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes) via build number alone, but although there is a `number:` locator, it can only be used in conjunction with `buildType:` (which is exactly the information I'm trying to identify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try build requests with build number locator in [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests).

We're using API method in PS script to retrieve builds by id like this:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$teamcityPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $teamcityUsername, $password

function GetBuild([string] $buildId) {
    $url = "$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:$buildId"
    Write-Host "GetBuild:$nl$url"

    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Credential $credentials -Verbose -WebSession $session
}
```

So i think you should be able to do similar with "number" locator:

```
$url = "$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/number:$buildNo"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried and that does indeed work. Despite the API docs specifically saying that `number:` is "to find build by build number, *provided build configuration is already specified*".